# Chrome is not applying the class changes on elements on Windows

Tags: android, jquery, css, windows, google-chrome

I have this very specific problem with Google Chrome which only occurs on Windows and Android, All the other major browsers work correctly. Even the Chrome itself works good on a Linux machine.

So here is the issue. I'm using jQuery to handle some animations and navigations. I have this button that when clicked brings another panel from the right edge of the screen by adding the `active` class to an element. You can see the live version of site [here](http://povfilm.ir).

In any browser other than Chrome clicking the [image] button will bring the said panel forth by adding `active` class to `.videos-wrapper` element which sets its width to 100%. In Chrome it doesn't work. I tried setting the width manually by using `$('.videos-wrapper').width($(window).width());` which does not work either.

The weird(er) part is in the inspection panel after applying the active class, if I uncheck and recheck the `width: 100%` property it works as expected.

I really don't know what else to do. So once again the live version can be found [here](http://povfilm.ir).
I would really appreciate it if someone could point out the problem.

Comment: Anybody figured out what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you are talking about that Chrome doesn't add active class to the section,
it does, but I would say that Chrome doesn't read incremental css classes correctly
I would rather create "videos-wrapper-active" class and apply rule to only this class not to
".videos-wrapper.active."

EDIT: The issue is that all elements have percents as dimension values, but at least the top parent should have a value in pixels. Otherwise 100% of 0px means nothing.

Comment: There is no point of having position: absolute on the videos-wrapper-active class. But now I see the issue actually, basically the percentage widths work like this that they take the value from parent.
But none of the parents have the value, it wont even help if you add width:100% to body, one of the parent actually needs the px value. Thats why if you hover over element in chrome it will show the width is 0.

Comment: Put some value in body's height like 500px. What I recommend is that on start you calculate window.inner height and width and set it to body, you wont be able to solve this with just percentage.

Comment: I really don't think that's the problem. Try this. Open the Inspection panel and find `.videos-wrapper-active` (after clicking the button). Uncheck the property `width:100%` and check it again. You'll see that it works.

Comment: I mean if it was beacuase of its parent not having a specific width height it wouldn't have worked this way either! Thanks for your time.